# When I delete from a LinkedList object vs. Deleting a node from given a head node why do I get different results?

Tags: java, linked-list

I think I know what the problem may be (a misunderstanding on Global vs. Local variables), but would like further verification on why it is not doing what I would like it to.

So, originally, I was just messing around and tried to implement the LinkedList delete method as follows :
(Also, I know most of this looks a mess right now, I think I am doing some bad practices, so you may be frank)

```
// Practicing with Lists...

public class ListPrac {



/*
Implement Delete for
singly-linked linked list
*/


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ListNode head = new ListNode(1);
      head.next = new ListNode(2);
      head.next.next = new ListNode(3);
      head.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
      delete(head, 1);
      System.out.println("done");


   }
   public static int delete(ListNode head, int deleteMe) {
      ListNode temp = head;
      ListNode prev = null;
      // need to check if it is first and 
      // need to check if it is at the end...
      if (temp != null && temp.dat == deleteMe) {
         temp = temp.next;
         return deleteMe;
      }
      // ^ two edge cases...
      while (temp != null) {
         int curVal = temp.dat;
         if (curVal == deleteMe && head.dat == curVal) {
            head = temp.next;
            return deleteMe; // done...
         }
         if (curVal == deleteMe) {
            if (temp.next != null) {
               prev.next = temp.next;
               return deleteMe; // done...
            }
         }
         prev = temp;
         temp = temp.next;
      }
      
      return -1; // not found, so not deleted...
   
   }


   public static class ListNode {
   
      int dat;
      ListNode next;
   
      public ListNode(int val) {
         dat = val;
         next = null;
      }
   
   }



}
```

When I debug this and check what the head looks like in the end, it still shows 1->2->3->4,
but as I went through the method, it seemed to be doing the right thing for when I removed a middle element (for ex, removing 3 yields giving me 1->2->4 at the end)

When looking at geeksforgeeks they implement it like this (and it works fine)
(this is just a snippet with delete rest can be found at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-3-deleting-node/):

```
class LinkedList1 
{ 
    Node head; // head of list 
  
    /* Linked list Node*/
    class Node 
    { 
        int data; 
        Node next; 
        Node(int d) 
        { 
            data = d; 
            next = null; 
        } 
    } 
  
    /* Given a key, deletes the first occurrence of key in linked list */
    void deleteNode(int key) 
    { 
        // Store head node 
        Node temp = head, prev = null; 
  
        // If head node itself holds the key to be deleted 
        if (temp != null && temp.data == key) 
        { 
            head = temp.next; // Changed head 
            return; 
        } 
  
        // Search for the key to be deleted, keep track of the 
        // previous node as we need to change temp.next 
        while (temp != null && temp.data != key) 
        { 
            prev = temp; 
            temp = temp.next; 
        }     
  
        // If key was not present in linked list 
        if (temp == null) return; 
  
        // Unlink the node from linked list 
        prev.next = temp.next; 
    } 
}
```

(There may be other things wrong with my code, but right now I am just focusing on removal of the first element not working)
I think the problem may be that I do not fully understand what is happening globally vs. locally if that makes sense?

---

For further clarification :
(Also further looking into it, I think there are a lot of differences in approach to mine vs. geeksforgeeks, but I think I narrowed down where my problem lies) Anyways, after moving some things around, I think my question is really about why their delete method works with a linked list object vs. just a linked list built using ListNodes in main, for example below :

```
 
// Practicing with Lists...

public class ListPrac1 {

   public static ListNode head;
   public static ListNode headExample; // the different example

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   
      ListPrac1 ll1= new ListPrac1();
      
      ll1.push(4); 
      ll1.push(3); 
      ll1.push(2); 
      ll1.push(1); 

      ll1.delete(1);
      System.out.println("done");
      System.out.println("\nLinked List after Deletion of 1:"); 
      ll1.printList(); 
      // This is what they did basically while creating a LinkedList
      // Object I guess and it works...
      
      // but... with the same structure of delete method and just 
      // using ListNodes to build a list starting with
      // variable headExample instead and then calling deleteMine.
      // (which has the same structure as delete except a reference to 
      // the new head...)
      ListNode headExample = new ListNode(1);
      headExample.next = new ListNode(2);
      headExample.next.next = new ListNode(3);
      headExample.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
      deleteMine(1);
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("\nLinked List starting with headExample after Deletion of 1:"); 

      while (headExample != null) {
         System.out.print(headExample.dat + " ");
         headExample = headExample.next;
      }
   }
   
   public static void printList() { 
        ListNode tnode = head; 
        while (tnode != null) 
        { 
            System.out.print(tnode.dat+" "); 
            tnode = tnode.next; 
        } 
   } 
    
   public static int delete(int deleteMe) {
 
        // Store head node 
        ListNode temp = head, prev = null; 
  
        // If head node itself holds the key to be deleted 
        if (temp != null && temp.dat == deleteMe) 
        { 
            head = temp.next; // Changed head 
            return deleteMe; 
        } 
  
        // Search for the key to be deleted, keep track of the 
        // previous node as we need to change temp.next 
        while (temp != null && temp.dat != deleteMe) 
        { 
            prev = temp; 
            temp = temp.next; 
        }     
  
        // If key was not present in linked list 
        if (temp == null) return -1; 
  
        // Unlink the node from linked list 
        prev.next = temp.next; 
        return deleteMe;

      
      
      
     
   
   }
   
   
   public static int deleteMine(int deleteMe) {
 
        // Store head node 
        ListNode temp = headExample, prev = null; 
  
        // If head node itself holds the key to be deleted 
        if (temp != null && temp.dat == deleteMe) 
        { 
            headExample = temp.next; // Changed head 
            return deleteMe; 
        } 
  
        // Search for the key to be deleted, keep track of the 
        // previous node as we need to change temp.next 
        while (temp != null && temp.dat != deleteMe) 
        { 
            prev = temp; 
            temp = temp.next; 
        }     
  
        // If key was not present in linked list 
        if (temp == null) return -1; 
  
        // Unlink the node from linked list 
        prev.next = temp.next; 
        return deleteMe;
   }

   
   
   public static void push(int new_data) { 
        ListNode new_node = new ListNode(new_data); 
        new_node.next = head; 
        head = new_node; 
   } 


   public static class ListNode {
   
      int dat;
      ListNode next;
   
      public ListNode(int val) {
         dat = val;
         next = null;
      }
   
   }
}
```

Output yields :
done
  Linked List after Deletion of 1:
 2 3 4
  Linked List starting with headExample after Deletion of 1:
 1 2 3 4

So it works for their way when creating a LinkedList, but not the other way where I make one with Nodes.

The delete and deleteMine methods are the same except deleteMine references headExample (which is what builds my second list in the second part)

So, my question really is:

1. Shouldn’t the delete work in both cases? Since both the LinkedList and headExample reference their respective head variables, why is headExample not being modified after delete, but the LinkedList ll1 is?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. You have a working implementation, compare it with your version and look for differences.  Are you asking US to do that for you?  If so, you have misunderstood the purpose of Stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: @JimGarrison Oh sorry, I thought that giving the comparison of two examples may illustrate where my confusion was better. I think I narrowed down my problem and have elaborated on that in an edit. (If this is also the wrong way to go about editing a problem vs. waiting and just posting at a later date, feel free to let me know, I am new to this)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem of your implementation is that you do not have a 'List'-object.
You have some instances of the ListNode class.

For a LinkedList you need to have an additional class that represents the List.
That List-class should have a ListNode variable that represents the head of the list. Look at the

```java
class LinkedList1 
{ 
    Node head; // head of list
```

part. It has a member named 'head'.
When the delete method is called it changes the head member variable of the list object.

If the class ListPrac represents your list a starting point could look like this:

```java
public class ListPrac {
    // each instance of ListPrac has a ListNode that represents the head of the list.
    ListNode head;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListPrac theList = new ListPrac();

      ListNode head = new ListNode(1);
      head.next = new ListNode(2);
      head.next.next = new ListNode(3);
      head.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
      
      // here we assign a ListNode as the head of the list.
      theList.head = head;
      // the delete method is invoked on the list. 
      theList.delete(1);
      //print the list to the console.
      System.out.println(theList);
   }

   // not static because we operate on a ListPrac instance.
   public int delete(int deleteMe) {

//...
   public static class ListNode {
   //...
      @Override
      public String toString(){
          String nextNodeAsString = next == null ? "null" : next.toString();
          return "{data="+dat+",next="+nextNodeAsString+"}";
      }
   }
//...

   @Override
   public String toString(){
        return "a list: {head="+head.toString()+"}";
   }

}
```

In the next step you should compare your and the other solution and try to spot the error.
Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks, I think I know where my misunderstanding lies a little bit better.